# How to make a Custom Login Flow reset password on Force Password Change

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have created a custom signin flow using the starter pack (with only changes for my ad tenant). I create a new user in Ad, with a temporary password that the user is forced to change on first signin.

When the user signs in for the first time, an error is displayed that the username/password is invalid, rather than going to a password reset page.

What changes do I need to make to the Custom signin flow so it presents a password reset page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS have provided a sample that describes how to enact the force password reset. See [Here](http://%20https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon).

This only works if you create the users programmatically. One point to note is you should make sure you set passwordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin to false when creating users.

Answer (score 0):

In the B2C sign-in flow, you cannot use the new created user with the temporary password. For the flow, it cannot redirect to the user change password page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can [create a new user with a random password using the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser), rather than using the Azure portal, then you can implement a custom policy that instructs the new user to reset the random password.

To implement this, you must [create a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#create-a-custom-attribute), e.g. **ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn**, set this custom attribute for the new user to `true`, and then test the custom attribute during the sign-in flow, as follows.

To set the custom attribute for the new user to `true`:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Alex Wu",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "AlexW@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "extension_<b2cExtensionApplicationObjectIdWithoutHyphens>_ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true
}
```

To test the custom attribute during the sign-in flow:

1. Declare a claim type that represents the custom attribute.

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn">
  <DisplayName>Force Change Password Next Sign-In</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

2. Declare [an **AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue** claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue) to ensure that the custom attribute isn't set to `true` (i.e. the new user doesn't have to reset to the random password).

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

3. Invoke the **EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse** claims transformations from a copy of the **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress** technical profile to test the custom attribute isn't set to `true`.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName-EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse">
  ...
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    ...
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    ...
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

4. Invoke the **AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName-EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse** technical profile from the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** technical profile to show an error message if the custom attribute is set to `true` (i.e. the new user does have to reset to the random password).

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  ...
  <Metadata>
    ...
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Whoops, you have to change your admin-created password, so please click 'Forgot your password?'.</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName-EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Great thxs again. We do create our own temporary password, so this will do the job.

Comment: I have tried doing as you suggest, but get error "Unable to validate the information provided".  The logging from app insights has this error "A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id "email" defined in technical profile with id "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-EnsureForceChangePasswordNextSignInIsFalse" policy "B2C_1A_Starter_MFA_signup_signin" of tenant". I have tested this applying your changes to the starter MFA expample.

Comment: Hi @DouglasWoods. I've edited the above answer to change from **UserReadUsingEmailAddress** to **UserReadUsingSignInName**. **UserReadUsingEmailAddress** was failing because the **email** claim didn't exist. **UserReadUsingSignInName** shouldn't fail because the **signInName** claim should exist.